# How to run OpenEDX on Centos 7 with cPanel

Tags: python, django, centos, cpanel, openedx

There are so many documentation about running OpenEDX on Ubuntu, but there is not any clear documentation how to run OpenEDX on CentOS specially with cPanel.
Anyone can help me regarding this case?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, there is no documentation for Open edX with CentOS because Open edX **requires** Ubuntu. Documentation [here](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/146440579/Native+Open+edX+Ubuntu+16.04+64+bit+Installation),
And the same question has been asked [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/edx-code/kWht5kzgQWw).

Answer (score 0):

I took "tutor" distribution which is in docker form, so it just ran smoothly over CentOS 7 of mine.